# Making specific style only apply to TableCell in Table body

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make a specific table in react using material UI.

Basically, the table itself has no lines separating the rows except for the one between table head and tablebody. From what I have found, I tried removing the bottom border from the table cell via overrides in the theme, but I do not know how to apply them back to only the specific TableCells in the TableHead. Here is the override in my theme:

```
overrides: {
    MuiTableCell: {
      root: {
        borderBottom: 'none'
      }
    },
```

Another approach that I could try is to apply the style via the Style param in each TableCell. What would be the most efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override MUI themes through `useStyles`. See the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/)

in your case let's say

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { TableCell } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  specificCell: {
    borderBottom: 'none';
  },
});



export default function Sample() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
      ...
      ...
      <TableCell className={classes.specificCell}> </TableCell>

  );
}
```